# How do i bin data into categories alphabetically using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame which includes a column containing a series of strings

```
books = pd.DataFrame([[1,'In Search of Lost Time'],[2,'Don Quixote'],[3,'Ulysses'],[4,'The Great Gatsby'],[5,'Moby Dick']], columns = ['Book ID', 'Title'])

   Book ID                   Title
0        1  In Search of Lost Time
1        2             Don Quixote
2        3                 Ulysses
3        4        The Great Gatsby
4        5               Moby Dick
```

And a sorted list of boundaries

```
boundaries = ['AAAAAAA','The Great Gatsby', 'zzzzzzzz']
```

I would like to use these boundaries to categorize the values in the data frame into alphabetical bins similarly to how `pd.cut()` works for numeric data.  My desire output would look something like the below.

```
   Book ID                   Title                          binning
0        1  In Search of Lost Time   ['AAAAAAA','The Great Gatsby')
1        2             Don Quixote   ['AAAAAAA','The Great Gatsby')
2        3                 Ulysses  ['The Great Gatsby','zzzzzzzz')
3        4        The Great Gatsby  ['The Great Gatsby','zzzzzzzz')
4        5               Moby Dick   ['AAAAAAA','The Great Gatsby')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `searchsorted`

```
boundaries = np.array(['The Great Gatsby'])
bins = np.array(['[A..The Great Gatsby)', '[The Great Gatsby..Z]'])

books.assign(binning=bins[boundaries.searchsorted(books.Title)])

   Book ID                   Title                binning
0        1  In Search of Lost Time  [A..The Great Gatsby)
1        2             Don Quixote  [A..The Great Gatsby)
2        3                 Ulysses  [The Great Gatsby..Z]
3        4        The Great Gatsby  [A..The Great Gatsby)
4        5               Moby Dick  [A..The Great Gatsby)
```

---

Expand this to some other set of boundaries:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
boundaries = np.array([*string.ascii_uppercase[1:-1]])
bins = np.array([f'[{a}..{b})' for a, b in zip(letters, letters[1:])])

books.assign(binning=bins[boundaries.searchsorted(books.Title)])

   Book ID                   Title binning
0        1  In Search of Lost Time  [I..J)
1        2             Don Quixote  [D..E)
2        3                 Ulysses  [U..V)
3        4        The Great Gatsby  [T..U)
4        5               Moby Dick  [M..N)
```

Comment: Thank you this works great,  i can even use the side parameter to control which bin 'The Great Gatsby' ended up in.